# NSURLConnection not working

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I need to open my php url from xcode and I am passing a variable in the url. I am performing the following code but it is not working, I have already checked that typing this url in the web browser works.

```
NSString *urlformatted = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://arcamm.uc3m.es/notifications/saveID.php?id=%@",deviceToken];

    NSLog(@"web service URL: %@", urlformatted);

    [urlformatted stringByAppendingString:[urlformatted stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlformatted] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    NSLog(@"connection: %@", [connection debugDescription]);
    if (connection) {
        NSLog(@"Connection succeeded");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed");
    }
```

It tells me the connection succeeded but the variable does not appear on my data base. And I am also getting the proper value of deviceToken.

EDIT: Found my error, I was receiving the deviceToken formatted so I did the following to scape <> and " "

```
NSString *deviceTokenString = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: If you have resolved the issue yourself, please post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Found my error, I was receiving the deviceToken formatted so I did the following to scape <> and " "

```
NSString *deviceTokenString = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```